# rendering to an IOSurface without NSOpenGLView

Tags: macos, opengl

I am trying to modify the Apple MultiGPUIOSurface sample (specifically the file http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MultiGPUIOSurface/Listings/ServerOpenGLView_m.html) so that the server side will render to an IOSurface, without the need for a NSOpenGLView.

My modified version of that is at: http://pastebin.com/z3r715jJ
The difference in my approach is I'm rendering to the IOSurface based on a timer, and not in drawRect. I also am not using the NSOpenGlView's context.

The problem is that I see a corrupt view of the IOSurface in the client application. However if I set the NSOpenGLView's context to the one I created, or use the context from the NSOpenGLView, it works. This leads me to think that the NSOpenGLView is doing something extra that I also need to do, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution (though I don't understand why): Create a pixelbuffer.

I found some discussion about offscreen buffers and the need for a drawable (http://www.mentby.com/Group/mac-opengl/opengl-offscreen-rendering-without-a-window.html)

Anyways, my fix was adding the lines:

```
        NSOpenGLPixelBuffer* pbuf = [[NSOpenGLPixelBuffer alloc] initWithTextureTarget:GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT textureInternalFormat:GL_RGBA textureMaxMipMapLevel:0 pixelsWide:512 pixelsHigh:512];

    [_nsContext setPixelBuffer:pbuf cubeMapFace:0 mipMapLevel:0 currentVirtualScreen:[_nsContext currentVirtualScreen]];
```